# Adding extra class apart from span5, sonata admin bundle

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata-admin

i have this

```
<div class="form-group controls sonata-ba-field sonata-ba-field-{{ sonata_admin.edit }}-{{ sonata_admin.inline }} {% if errors|length > 0 %}sonata-ba-field-error{% endif %} {% if not has_label %}sonata-collection-row-without-label{% endif %}">

    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        <div class="help-inline sonata-ba-field-error-messages">
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if sonata_admin.field_description.help %}
        <span class="help-block sonata-ba-field-help">{{ sonata_admin.admin.trans(sonata_admin.field_description.help, {}, sonata_admin.field_description.translationDomain)|raw }}</span>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

This form_widget creates the fields on a sonata edit page, however by default it has the `class="span5"`

I would like to edit it so it also has

```
form-control
```

i tried to modify the twig by setting the attributes manually but then the extra classes that are defined in admin controllers don't get applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that it is hardcoded in a service definition... so you have to redifine the service.

this is how you do it

```
sonata.admin.form.extension.field:
        class: Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Extension\Field\Type\FormTypeFieldExtension
        tags:
            - {name: form.type_extension, alias: form}
        arguments:
            - email: 'form-control'
              textarea: 'form-control'
              text: 'form-control'
              choice: 'form-control'
              integer: 'form-control'
              datetime: 'sonata-medium-date'
              date: 'sonata-medium-date'
```